# VLAN / Netplan / Ubuntu / configuration for static IPs creates additional dynamic IPs

Tags: networking, netplan, vlan

I setup a ubuntu 20.04 as a server of IOT, multimedia, ... My Network is separated in different VLANS to control where the IOT devices are allowed to talk with.

The Network itself is managed with unify USG3 and mangeds switches.

My current problem is following:

On Ubuntu 20.04 I use netplan to configure the network.

My .yaml for netplan looks like

```
network:
  ethernets:
    enp1s0:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses:
      - 192.168.1.17/24
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 192.168.1.17
        search:
        - roliko.lan
  version: 2
  vlans:
    enp1s0.100:
      addresses:
      - 192.168.100.17/24
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      id: 100
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      link: enp1s0
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 192.168.1.17
        search:
        - roliko.lan
    enp1s0.200:
      addresses:
      - 192.168.200.17/24
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      id: 200
      link: enp1s0
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 192.168.1.17
        search:
        - roliko.lan
```

This configuration works, an the computer is availabel with the different ips x.17, y.17 and z.17.

My Problem is, that additional ip adresses can be used.

```
2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 192.168.1.17/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global enp1s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp1s0.100@enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 192.168.100.17/24 brd 192.168.100.255 scope global enp1s0.100
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.100.78/24 brd 192.168.100.255 scope global secondary noprefixroute enp1s0.100
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: enp1s0.200@enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 192.168.200.17/24 brd 192.168.200.255 scope global enp1s0.200
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.200.38/24 brd 192.168.200.255 scope global secondary noprefixroute enp1s0.200
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Entries for .100.78 and .200.38 were created.

Does anybody know this behavior and knows how to configure netplan correct that these DHCP repated addresses are not created?

Thanks in advanced
Roland

Comment: there's nothing in your netplan config that explains these additional addresses, and I've never seen this behavior before.  Are you sure you don't have additional network management daemons installed on your system that are registering these addresses?  Also, you have specified `gateway4` addresses on your interfaces that are not on the same subnet as your interface; this is unrelated, but incorrect

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.I use a raw installation. Also installed docker. I found out that `dhcpcd` was running. First tried to disable the service using `denyinterfaces` in `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` without any effect. After disabling dhcpcd service now it works. 

Also `gateway4` entry is now corrected.

Comment: Thanks for following up.  Can you clarify what you mean by a 'raw installation'? It's unclear to me how you wound up with the `dhcpcd5` package installed, it is not part of any default Ubuntu install.  If something has pulled this in to satisfy a dependency on the virtual package `dhcp-client`, that implies you have started from an unclean base, because `isc-dhcp-client` which also implements `dhcp-client` is part of the `minimal` Ubuntu task.

Comment: With "raw installation" I mean, that i used a new installation. I double checked  /var/log/apt/history.log and found out that the installation of `dhcpcd5` seemed to be installed by myself when installing `dnsutils` by accident.

Comment: And thanks pushing me to find out when and why `dhcpcd5` was installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that `dhcpd5` was installed. After disabling `dhcpd5` the problem was solved.